# using combobox value

Tags: pygtk

Thanks S. Lott for your prompt reply.

My question was about this link in my first post:

[Python GTK adding signal to a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705547/python-gtk-adding-signal-to-a-combo-box)

I want to reuse the changed value of the combo in the main window GUI

Is it possible this way, and how ?

Thanks for some explanations

Best regards

Comment: I dont understand your question! If you want to get index of active item in combobox? then use `combo.get_active()`. and if you want to get data (ex: text) of selected item, you have the index from `combo.get_active()` and model from `combo.get_model()`, then whats the problem? `item = combo.get_model()[combo.get_active()]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a ComboBox with your own custom model, you can always get data for selected item:

```
index = combo.get_active()
model = combo.get_model()
item = model[index]
print item[0] ## , item[1], ...
```

But if you are using a text combobox (created with `gtk.combo_box_new_text()`), that's easier to use:

```
item_text = combo.get_active_text()
print item_text
```